# Slug Formatting : Acceptable Characters?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

I have done a lot of googling on this so I sincerely apologize if there is a codex entry for this but for the life of me I can not find a hard and fast rule about what characters are acceptable in a "slug" ( any slug really, but more specifically for a custom post type in this instance).

Presently we have a situation where we have a few custom post types with a slug structure like (pseudo) :

`some_Context_Thats_Not_A_Category_slug/sub_context_thats_not_a_category_slug/` +  the post title

The segment in `grey` is the "slug" in it's entirety. In practice this would look like say :

`hamburgers/cheeseburgers`  as the post type slug

Is the forward slash use allowed / safe in this scenario?

Criteria for an answer to be accepted:

"yes" or "no" to the question posed and a link to where I can find contemporary WP slug rulesets.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, forward slashes are not allowed to be used in slugs. However, they are automatically stripped out when trying to include slashes in a slug on the post editing screen. Slugs are sanitized by using `sanitize_title()`.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to explain what is and isn't allowed in a slug, let alone to give a simple set of rules to which valid slugs must adhere. However, we can summarise the most important characteristics of a slug quite compactly: **a slug consists of solely lowercase alphanumeric characters, dashes and underscores, without 2 or more dashes in a row (sequences of underscores *are* allowed). Furthermore, a slug cannot start or end with a hyphen.**

## sanitize_title()

Parameters:

- `$title`: Title to be sanitized
- `$fallback_title` (optional, defaults to empty string): Slug to use if the sanitized `$title` turns out empty
- `$content` (optional, defaults to 'save'): The operation for which the string is sanitized

The function `sanitize_title` behaves in the following way (by default, with default `$fallback_title` and `$context` arguments, with  no external filters applied):

1. Accented characters such as "é" and "Ö" are replaced by their corresponding "unaccented" characters (in this example, "e" and "O", respectively)
2. `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` is called on the resulting string

The longer (and more complete) explanation can be found below.

## sanitize_title_with_dashes()

Besides the `$title` parameter, `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` has two more arguments, the first of which isn't used, and second of which is the content, `$context`, which is passed from `sanitize_title` (and is thus 'save'). `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` does a lot of things, so I'll try to explain what sequence of steps it performs to sanitize a string.

1. All HTML tags are stripped
2. Percentage signs are removed, except for the ones in octets (such as `%20` for space)
3. The string is converted to lowercase
4. All HTML entities, such as `&amp;` are stripped
5. All dots (`.`) are replaced by hyphens (`-`)
6. Both en dashes and em dashes ([WikiPedia on dashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)), as well as spaces, are converted to hyphens
7. Some special characters, such as accents (e.g. the grave accent) are stripped
8. The "times" character ([`×`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign)) is replaced by "x"
9. All characters except for alphanumerical characters, spaces, hyphens and underscores are stripped
10. Sequences of hyphens (2 or more hyphens in a row) are replaced by a single hyphen
11. Leading and trailing hyphens are stripped

And there you have it, the full title-sanitization process!