# Wordpress matching URLs with trailing tildes code correction

Tags: rewrite-rules

Asking why Wordpress matching URLs with trailing tildes

[Wordpress matching URLs with trailing tildes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208733/wordpress-matching-urls-with-trailing-tildes)

[image]

Prevent matching
`add_rewrite_tag` is a function that, despite its name, can be used to update an existing rewrite tag like `%postname%`.

So, if we use the code:

```
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_tag( '%postname%', '([^~/]+)', 'name=' );
});
```

we will reach our target and example.com/postname~ will not match the rule for example.com/postname.

So, yes, the 3 lines above is the only code you'll need.

My Question is what file(s) would that code be inserted?

Comment: Usually your (child) theme's functions.php or your whatever-your-custom-plugin-name-is.php - or any file that is included in any of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web)

Comment: Thanks for I made a plugins/directory/file under plugins called: trailing-tilde-fix/trailing-tilde-fix.php with and Activated the plugin.. it does not remove trailing ~ with a 404 as I wish.

Comment: You have to visit the Permalinks Settings page in admin to flush rewrites rules.

Comment: Thanks Milo, I did visit the page, and did a save --my custom plugin to get rid of the trailing ~ bug however does not work...