# Where to add add_rewrite_tag for trailing tilde?

Tags: rewrite-tag

Ive just been reading @gmazzap s reply about [wordpress matching URLs with trailing tildes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208733/wordpress-matching-urls-with-trailing-tildes).

and could do with some help please. As a coding newbie, I am not sure where to add his suggested code:

```
add_action('init', function() {
  add_rewrite_tag( '%postname%', '([^~/]+)', 'name=' );
});
```

Functions.php, /includes/rewrite.php, or somewhere else...

Also what are the implications of doing this, when wordpress updates, will these changes be lost? Am running a child theme.
Sorry to ask such basic questions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should add this to `functions.php` file of your child theme. Changes wouldn't be lost on WP updates.

Comment: If you're running a child theme, then it's generally safe to add code in your theme's `functions.php` file. So just add the code there in that file.

Comment: I'm not sure if it applies to add_rewrite_tag, but after add_rewrite_rule() you must call flush_rewrite_rules() once, and ideally once only as it can be very slow. So if you call add_rewrite_tag and it doesn't seem to work this could be why. There's more good info here: https://carlalexander.ca/wordpress-adventurous-rewrite-api/

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses so far. So I added the code to functions.php of my child theme and then did save in the permalinks area of the wp dashboard. I also cleared the superccache. At the moment, the site is still serving up pages with trailing~ . How long should I expect it to take to flush?