# swedish charater åäö in permalinks

Tags: permalinks

I'm wondering how to add swedish charater åäö in permalinks (slug). Today when i try to change slug with åäö it´s replace with aao

e.g. www.domina.com/jämföra/ transform to www.domina.com/jamfora/

i have try to set charset utf-8 in database table in wp-config.php

*/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */*
*define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use åäö in slugs, only a-z, 0-9 and - is allowed if I recall correct.

Comment: but look at this how use wordpress and have ä in the slug site: http://kvalitetsflytt.se/städ/

Comment: @LePung I think this is done on the server level, in .htaccess or something. It is not possible to save slugs with åäö.
See this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149191/slug-formatting-acceptable-characters